# Predicate returns false when accounts along with oracle is used in corda

Tags: corda

I'm trying to use accounts functionality in corda along with oracle functionality, problem lies with building a filtered function for getting oracle signature. my kotlin code, which used predicate to check whether my transaction has oracle key in it always returns false, even though I have oracle publickey added in list of public keys used for signing initial transactions.

```
var requiredSigners = Arrays.asList(oracle.owningKey, urIdentity.owningKey, lenderAccountNewKey)
val output = IOUState(exchangeRate * value, lenderAccountNewKey, borrowerAccountNewKey)
    val transactionBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
    var participantsList = ArrayList<AbstractParty>(output.participants)
    participantsList.add(oracle)
    transactionBuilder.addOutputState(output, IOUContract.ID)
            .addCommand(IOUContract.Commands.Create(), participantsList.map { it.owningKey })
    transactionBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

 var localSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(transactionBuilder)

        var filteredTx = localSignedTx.buildFilteredTransaction(Predicate {
            when (it) {
                is Command<*> -> oracle.owningKey in it.signers
                else -> false
            }
        }
val oracleSignature = subFlow(SignFlow(oracle, filteredTransaction))
    val stx = locallySignedTransaction.withAdditionalSignature(oracleSignature)
```

when tried to run with the following code, the logs are given below.

> [INFO ] 2020-05-26T07:00:59,660Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow. - Flow raised an error: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.. Sending it to flow hospital to be triaged.
>   {actor_id=internalShell, actor_owning_identity=O=PartyA, L=London,
>   C=GB, actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG, fiber-id=10000003,
>   flow-id=040d69f9-f93a-4a23-bdb4-594c41d38987,
>   invocation_id=3da3d8a0-64ec-4a41-8f18-b0ca05557490,
>   invocation_timestamp=2020-05-26T07:00:58.102Z, origin=internalShell,
>   session_id=dec88c8e-1441-425b-bfe0-f00ad6b12126,
>   session_timestamp=2020-05-26T06:58:59.126Z, thread-id=161} [INFO ]
>   2020-05-26T07:00:59,666Z [Node thread-1]
>   statemachine.StaffedFlowHospital. - Flow
>   [040d69f9-f93a-4a23-bdb4-594c41d38987] admitted to hospital in state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should pass `requiredSigners` list when you specify the command; currently you are passing `participantsList`.
- On a side note, an oracle shouldn't be a participant; it's usually a third party that provides verified data.
  What's the point of sending the oracle a filtered transaction, if you're going to register that full transaction and relevant states inside the oracle by making it a participant (assuming `participantsList` is what you're going to use in your finality flow).
- You should use the `WireTransaction` to build the filtered transaction (i.e. `localSignedTx.tx.buildFilteredTransaction()`) (notice the `.tx`).
- You have a typo, you use `filteredTransaction` in `SignFlow`; your variable name is `filteredTx`.